# Selenium Python Empty return after page update

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, scrape

I am using Selenium Python together with BeautifulSoup to scrape data.
I need the website's html after the 'Live' button is clicked. I am getting the button to be clicked, however the new HTML is not returned to me.
I thought the html was being returned very quickly after the button clicked, so I put a sleep. But even so it is returning only the empty div of the class 'Collapsible__contentInner'.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://www.365scores.com/pt-br/football'

web_r = requests.get(url)
web_soup = BeautifulSoup(web_r.text, 'html.parser')

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

botaoPopUp = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/button')))
botaoPopUp.click()

elemento = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]')
elemento.click()

import time 
time.sleep(10)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
dados = soup.find('div', class_="Collapsible__contentInner")
print(dados)
```

RESULT

```
<div class="Collapsible__contentInner"><div style="position: relative;"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the page_source.

Access the element directly using the web driver:

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.Collapsible__contentInner')

You can then access the content of that element uor the attributes, see the selenium docks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all getting all HTML source of page and then **scraping** a few element attributes is not a very wise idea. Still if you want to get the HTML source of page using **page_source** is not a very reliable idea, as it does not guarantee it would return current state of page HTML source. Instead use JavaScript outerHTML like below:

```
html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
```